# document.getElementById().value as a variable won't work

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var random1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8));
var questionting    = document.getElementById('wagwan').value;
 
function dothething(){
  if (random1 === 0){
   document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "You asked:" + questionting + " And my finna woke answer is yes.";
  }
  else if (random1 === 1){
       document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "You asked: " + questionting +  ". My finna woke answer is nah mate.";

  }
  else if (random1 === 2){
     document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "You asked: "  + questionting  + ". My finna woke answer is that I dunno G.";

  }
  else if (random1 === 3){
       document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "You asked: " + questionting  + ". My finna woke answer is that you should try again later my B.";

  }
  else if (random1 === 4){
           document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "You asked: "  + questionting  + ". My finna woke answer is that it's looking good.";

  }
  else if (random1 === 5){
          document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "You asked: "  + questionting  + ". My finna woke answer is that it finna be.";

  }
  else if (random1 === 6){
           document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "You asked: "  + questionting  + ". My finna woke answer is that my finna sources say no.";

  }
  else if (random1 === 7){
          document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "You asked: " + questionting +  ". My finna woke answer is that you should look towards the audiovisual counsel of our overlord Shrek in this time of turbulance and malhappenings.";

  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <p1> Enter ur question and I'll give you my finna woke answer </p1> <br>  
<input id="wagwan" type="text" name="FirstName" value=""><br>
<button onclick="dothething()"> Get yo finna woke answer </button>
<p id="answer">Enter your question and we finna know whatta do<p>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to create a magic-8 ball using JavaScript for a school project, however when trying to declare    `var questionting = document.getElementById('wagwan').value;`    the variable will not return any value of any sort when called upon for an output (see image). I have spent a while trying to fix this but I haven't been able to find a solution which makes any difference works.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJ9ZK.png)

Comment: Where are you placing script tag in html? I'd suggest to read javascript fundamental docs though.

Comment: It’s going to store the value of the `value` property at the time you assigned it to `questioning`, yes. If you had `var number = parseInt(prompt('Enter a number'));`, would you expect nothing to show up until you ran `number + number`, then expect it to ask for two numbers at that point?

Comment: yo need to execute `var questionting    = document.getElementById('wagwan').value;` **inside** `dothething` ... because `questionting` doesn't change when the input changes

Comment: and calc random1 inside function dothething (){};

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! We value questions with minimal example code - delete until the problem either goes away (then you're close to fixing yourself) or until you can't delete anything anymore. See the [stackoverflow help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more details. For instance, none of the CSS is required. In addition, [in text we value clarity as well - there is no need to say "hi", "thank" or similar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). I took the liberty of editing your answer to that effect.

Answer (score 3):

Youre declaring

```
var questionting    = document.getElementById('wagwan').value;
```

at a time, where is not have a value yet.

Put it in your dosomething()-method and try it again.

Comment: More precisely, there isn't even a guarantee that the input element is already in the DOM by the time the code is executed.

Comment: A few other points:

function should take an argument, e.g random1...

    var questionting = document.getElementById('wagwan').value;     won't work

declare answer variable:
    var answer = document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML;    

Then either declare before assigning, as:

    var questionting = document.getElementById('wagwan');    
    questionting = answer;    

or assign directly, as:

    document.getElementById('wagwan').value = answer;